# Linux/ Unix (How to block ports for particular process)

Tags: linux

Is there any way so that I can block port to a particular application. I need to block the port for the tsm backup.How to do it?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4314163/create-iptables-rule-per-process-service

Comment: Ha! Long time ago I invented a kernel mode patch for that. It was called xt_appf for 3.2.12 kernel. It was able to use it with OUTPUT table for every program and it matched by it's /proc/self/exe symlink contents. Now I don't support it and do not use it because I found a way to patch xt_owner to extend it to groups marker and match by assigning a gid to groups that process have.

Comment: Do you mean _reserve_ a particular port for a particular application? You want to make sure the tsm backup has exclusive access to a port? Or you wnat it to _not_ use a port. In case you don't know, you can tell tsm which port to use on the client side. It's `TCPClientPort` in `dsm.sys`